# How do you pass a file list to the linux zip command

Tags: linux, svn, git, zip, export

I'm using Git for version control and unlike SVN I have not come across an inherent means of performing an export of changed files between 2 revisions, branches or tags.

As an alternative I want to use the linux zip command and pass it a set of file names, however the file names are the result of another command git diff. Below is an example of what I am trying to achieve:

```
zip /home/myhome/releases/files.zip git diff --name-only -a 01-tag 00-tag
```

However the above does not work as I guess the 'zip' command sees the git operation as part of its command options.

Does someone know how I can make something like the above work?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to execute the git command in a sub-shell:

```
zip /home/myhome/releases/files.zip `git diff --name-only -a 01-tag 00-tag`
# another syntax (assuming bash):
zip /home/myhome/releases/files.zip $(git diff --name-only -a 01-tag 00-tag)
```

Another option is the [xargs](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?xargs) command:

```
git diff --name-only -a 01-tag 00-tag | xargs zip /home/myhome/releases/files.zip
```

Comment: It's more accurate to say you need to execute the git command via `command substitution`.  Command substitution uses a sub-shell, but a sub-shell is a more general concept used in other ways as well (see http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/subshells.html#SUBSHELLSREF)

Answer (score 3):

If you're in a git shell (bash) you can also do this:

```
git diff -–name-only commit1 commit2 | zip ../Changes.zip –@
```

Works for me on Windows and Unix based systems.

Comment: It should be noted, that this doesn't work an MacOS according to the ``zip`` man pages.